# How to make a variable that stores a previous turn's value

Tags: python

I'm doing an assignment on a dice roll game. Currently, I'm trying to create a variable that returns the previous score value so that it can be used to compare with the number of dice is rolled. However, i'm having trouble having the previous score update to the current score through every turn.

I currently have a placeholder variable to store a value with previous_score = 0. Is there a way to have my variable previous_score update to the current_score's value through each iteration in the while loop? Currently in PyCharm it says that the local variable 'previous_score' value is not used in previous_score = current_score. Also, is there a better place to put the previous_score so that it will have the previous turn's value?

Also, if this helps, we're not supposed to use a solution that is complicated as the class assumes we don't know a lot about Python.

Here is my code to give more context - I have previous_score = 0 and previous_score = current_score:

```
def play(strategy0, strategy1, score0=0, score1=0, dice=six_sided,
         goal=GOAL_SCORE, say=silence, feral_hogs=True):  
  who = 0
     while score0 < goal and score1 < goal:
        if who == 0:
            num_dice = strategy0(score0, score1)
            current_turn = take_turn(num_dice, score1, dice)
            previous_score = 0
            if abs(num_dice - previous_score) == 2 and feral_hogs:
                previous_score = current_turn
                current_turn += 3
                score0 += current_turn
            else:
                return False 
            if is_swap(score0, score1):
                score0, score1 = score1, score0
            else:
                score0, score1 = score0, score1
            who = other(who)
        else:
            num_dice = strategy1(score1, score0)
            current_turn = take_turn(num_dice, score0, dice)
            previous_score = 0
            if abs(num_dice - previous_score) == 2 and feral_hogs:
                previous_score = current_turn
                current_turn += 3
                score1 += current_turn
            else:
                return False
            if is_swap(score1, score0):
                score1, score0 = score0, score1
            else:
                score1, score0 = score1, score0
            who = other(who)
    return score0, score1
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.   Your posted code is not properly indented.  It contains several undefined symbols.  The function header is illegal, and you never call the function.

Comment: PyCharm is correct: you set `previous_score` to zero just before it's only reference.  Setting it to `current_score` never gets used.  In general, you *initialize* your variable before the loop, then update it within the loop.  You failed to explain the logic or game mechanics, but I suspect that your problem will be repaired if you simply "lift" that initilization out of the loop: put it *before* the `while`.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you want to pick a good starting value for `previous_score` that you can use without too much fuss.

For example, if you start with `previous_score = None` then you may find yourself writing code like this a lot:

```
if previous_score is not None:
    do_something()
```

On the other hand, `None` might work for you if all you ever do is check for true/false, since `None` is false-y by default.

```
if previous_score:
    do_something()
```

If you are doing math, though, it's probably best if you start with 0:

```
previous_score = current_score = 0
```

Once you get things set up, the general rule is to write your loop, and set the `previous_score` only at the end of the loop:

```
previous_score = current_score = 0

while keep_going:
    current_score = compute_current_score()
 
    blah_blah(current_score)
  
    if current_score > previous_score:
        do_something()
    else:
        do_something_else()

    previous_score = current_score
    # This is the end of the loop
```

This means that the first time through the loop, `previous_score` will be set to 0 (where it was set outside the loop). But each time after that, it will take on the previous value.

In this particular instance, you can get away with merging the two assignments at the top of the loop:

```
current_score = 0  # No assignment to previous_score here, it moves down
while keep_going:
    previous_score = current_score 

    ... rest as before

    # no assignment to previous_score here, it's at the top
```

This works because the assignment is simple and easy. You will eventually find an assignment that is complex or hard, and have to move things down.